# How to read certains values of some files in R?

Tags: r, loops

I have 6 folders with 10 files each. Every file contains 100 coordinates.

I want to create a loop or something similar to choose specific coordinates in each files.

I tried subset, but i don't know how to create a loop with it.

What should i try? 
Thank you!!

An example:
i have 2 folders in a directory call "folder". Each folder has 2 files. Each file has 4 rows. Each rows has 3 variables (latitude, longitude and value).

eg.      lat  lon  va
        (-3    2    5),
        (-3    1    6),
        (-3    4    4),

So, imagine I want lat -3, lon 4, with va 4, and this lat and lon is in every file in every folder.

I used, as someone explain to me,

```
file <- list.files(path = "D:\\folder\\", recursive= TRUE )
```

and it works.

Now I have all files "together"

then I tried the following sentence:

```
rbind(lapply(file, subset, V1 == -3))
```

and this is what I get:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irh4Y.png)

What should I do?

Comment: This is actually two questions: (1) how to read multiple files efficiently, and (2) how to subset that data. For the first, something like `do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(filelist, read.csv))` is a good start. For the second, `subset` or simple `[` indexing should be sufficient. It would help if you made this question self-contained and reproducible, with an example file or two and conditions on your filtering. Most importantly, please include code you've used to attempt this feat.

Comment: Hello Jack, welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm afraid we need more information than this to answer your question. Are the files CSV? XML? PNG? Excel? Bitmaps? Binary? .RData? How are you reading them into R? What code are you using just now? Please don't leave folks here guessing important information that you could easily add to your question, otherwise we won't be able to help you.

Comment: (And for your sake, please don't delay ... it's not uncommon to see questions that appear vague or needing clarity to either be closed within an hour. It doesn't happen all the time, but it really helps if you are responsive to suggestions, especially within the first hour. Thanks!)

Comment: Sorry, first time here and i was trying to explain everything.

Comment: You may be able to use `file <- list.files(path = "D:\folder", recursive = TRUE)` to get all the files in all the folders at once and not need a loop.

Comment: Thanks Gregor, So now i have all the files together. Second question is to get the information I need using the coordinates instead of the position in the files. Thanks for your answer!!